# Set counting javascript program to two decimal places

Tags: javascript, html, decimal, counting

Please see this code:

```
<script>
setInterval(function () {
    var counters = document.getElementsByClassName("count");

    for(var i = 0 ; i < counters.length ; i++) {
        counters[i].innerHTML = parseInt(counters[i].innerHTML) + parseInt(counters[i].dataset.increment);
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

What it does is take a piece of html like this:

```
<div class="count" data-increment="10">10</div>
```

And it will count by 10 every second.  How do I make the following code work:

```
<div class="count" data-increment="10.02">10.02</div>
```

Basically, I want to have this program count by up to two decimal places.

Comment: Easy... Use parseFloat instead of parseInt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bdcm8mmq/1/)
 You need to use parseFloat to covert string to float.
  and toFixed on float to truncate extra decimal. toFixed return string you need to use parseFloat again so that it became float addition not string concatenation.

```js
var counters = document.getElementsByClassName("count");
    
    setInterval(function () {
        for(var i = 0 ; i < counters.length ; i++) {
            
            counters[i].innerHTML = (parseFloat(parseFloat(counters[i].innerHTML).toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(parseFloat(counters[i].dataset.increment).toFixed(2))).toFixed(2);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="count" data-increment="10">10</div>

<div class="count" data-increment="10.02">10.02</div>
```

Comment: This is almost perfect.. sometimes it gives a number like 43.3599999999999 is there a way to just limit it to 2 decimals..?

Comment: @Disguy fixed check now

Comment: Thanks for the help man that works.  I gotta figure out how the hell you did this :P

Answer (score 3):

Use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`. And `toFixed(2)` for limiting two decimal points.

```
setInterval(function() {
    var counters = document.getElementsByClassName("count");

    for (var i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
        counters[i].innerHTML = parseFloat(counters[i].innerHTML).toFixed(2) + parseFloat(counters[i].dataset.increment).toFixed(2);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This doesnt work... it just puts another number next to the first one but doesnt count like the original one does...

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping addition within `String()` , `.innerHTML` , `.dataset` within `Number()` , `Number()` within expression `()` chained to `.toFixed(2)` ; set `counters[i].innerHTML` to result derived within `String((Number(/* innerHTML */) + Number(/* dataset *)).toFixed(2))`

```js
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  var counters = document.getElementsByClassName("count");

  for (var i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
    counters[i].innerHTML = String((Number(counters[i].innerHTML) 
                            + Number(counters[i].dataset.increment)).toFixed(2));

  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="count" data-increment="10.02">10.02</div>
```